# Connecting points in a for loop with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.5pt]
        \filldraw [fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm]
        \foreach \i in {0,30,...,360} {--(\i:2.8) node{$\bullet$}};
        \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
        {\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:2.8cm) -- (\angle:3cm);
            \node[font=\large] at (\angle:2.2cm) {\xi};}
        \foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270};
        \foreach \angle in {60,30,...,-270}
        {\draw[fill=black] (\angle:2.8cm) circle (0.1pt);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

This code produces

[image: 1]

Following the code given in the answers I managed to produce and connect all the dots in a clock. Now there is one additional line from number 3 (or `90:2.8` I suppose) to the center of the clock which I don't want. You can see it clearly in the diagram. Why is it coming and how to remove it?

Comment: Have a look at `/pgf/foreach/remember`.

Comment: So I added `\foreach \angle [remember=\angle as \xyz] in {60,30,...,-270}` this to the code on the relevant line, still I have to start a line from one point and end it at another, how code this?

Comment: You can set the initial value with `initially`: `\foreach \angle [remember=\angle as \lastangle (initially 90)]
   in {60,30,...,-270}
        {\draw[fill=black] (\angle:2.8cm) circle[radius=1pt];   
        \draw (\lastangle:2.8cm) -- (\angle:2.8cm);
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: the clock as updated question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cyan]
\draw (0:2.8) \foreach \i in {0,30,...,360} {--(\i:2.8) node{$\bullet$}};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
\draw[thick] (\i:2.8)--(\i:3) (\i:2.2) node[scale=1.2,orange]{\xi};
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) circle(3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a way:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(3) (0:2.8) \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330} {--(\i:2.8) node{$\bullet$}}--cycle;   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://pastebin.com/ceTBBAZV) code. I don't want the line connecting the center and number 3. This is what I exactly wanted to achieve, but as it wasn't minimal I shortened it to the code given above.

Comment: @Niranjan Now I know you want to draw a clock,but honestly I don't not get your point. Can you add a picture on your question?

Comment: Yes. Please check the edit.

Comment: @Niranjan Is it what you want? `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0:2.8) \foreach \i in {0,30,...,360} {--(\i:2.8) node{$\bullet$}};
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
\draw[thick] (\i:2.8)--(\i:3) (\i:2.2) node[scale=1.2]{\xi};
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) circle(3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Niranjan The reason there is a line from the center to to right is: `\filldraw [fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm]
        \foreach \i in {0,30,...,360} {--(\i:2.8) node{$\bullet$}};` , so at first step of `\foreach`, the origin (0,0) is connnected to (0:2.8)

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I want :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Another way with `tkz-euclide`

The clock:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,ms/.style={teal,line width=.8mm}]
\foreach \an [count=\i] in {60,30,...,-270}
{ \tkzDefPoint(\an:2.8){\i}
  \tkzDrawSegment[ms]({\an:2.8},{\an:3})} 
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDrawCircle[R,teal,line width=1.6mm](O,3 cm)
  \tkzDrawPolygon[ms](1,...,12) 
  \tkzDrawPoints[teal,size=6](1,...,12) 
  \tkzAutoLabelPoints[purple,font=\Large,center=O,dist=-0.1](1,...,12) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \an [count=\i] in {0,30,...,360}
{ \tkzDefPoint(\an:2.8){A_\i}} 
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,3 cm)
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A_1,A_...,A_12) 
  \tkzDrawPoints(A_1,A_...,A_12) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]